# What is と doing here after this list?

Tags: particle-と, coordination

I'm trying to understand this sentence, particularly how と works here.

> 朝から、算数、国語、社会、理科と退屈な授業が続く。

Comment: I wonder if this と is the same one asked in this question: [https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/68125/](Function of と when used with 続く)...

Answer (score 1):

> 「朝{あさ}から、算数{さんすう}、国語{こくご}、社会{しゃかい}、理科{りか}**と**退屈{たいくつ}な授業{じゅぎょう}が続{つづ}く。」

「と」 here means the same thing as 「といった」, 「など」, 「のような」, etc.  Strictly speaking, 「という」 is not included here.

It is used to list ***multiple*** examples (in this case, the four classes/subjects) of what one is speaking about (here, 「退屈な授業」= "boring classes/subjects").

"Multiple" is *the* key word.  This 「と」 ***could not*** be used if only one example were being given.  You must use 「という」 in that case.

Comment: @l'électeur Isn't this *pretty* different from 「のような」? I feel like it's applying the "drudging" sound of a long list of classes to "退屈な授業が続く". In other words, the actual sound seems important to me (c.f., "Math, English, Social Studies, Science---the tedious classes continued."). But maybe I'm misunderstanding what 「と」 this is.