# Function of と in Xと人気になる

Tags: grammar, particle-と

> 青森県鰺ヶ沢町の店にいる雄の犬の「わさお」は、１０年前にインターネットで紹介されて、ライオンのように長い毛と小さな目がかわいい**と**人気になりました。
>   Wasao, a male dog in a shop in xxx was shown on the internet ten years ago and, *with* cute lion-like fur and small eyes, became popular.

I can't work out the grammatical function of と (in bold) in this sentence. The only と I know that can come after an i-adjective is either the conditional or the quotative. The conditional certainly doesn't make sense to me.

My only guess is that this is quotative with a missing verb. I was thinking maybe I could insert 思われて after と. But I fear I may be way off here.

Comment: I feel this is quite similar to what I just asked https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/68125/function-of-%E3%81%A8-when-used-with-%E7%B6%9A%E3%81%8F

Comment: @shade549 Hmm, possibly, but I'm struggling to see anything but a very tenuous connection. I'm not reading that and thinking "Ah! now I understand" when I apply it to my sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It literally means people praised it, saying (/thinking that) its long (lion-like) fur and small eyes were cute. In this context と simply indicates that whatever precedes it is the words of a specific person, an opinion of some people in general, etc. So yes, you could think of it as a 'quotation particle'.

Another example of how you could use it is 「簡単にはやられまいと、決死の覚悟で応戦する」. It's used as if the 「簡単にはやられまい」was a quote, even though it might actually only indicate a person's thoughts, beliefs, or something to that effect.