# Usage of と particle in a a literary description

Tags: grammar, particle-と

In the novel **二銭銅貨** by **江戸川乱歩**, I'm wondering the use of と particle in the following sentence :

> 十数名の賃銀計算係が、五千人近い職工のタイム・カードから、それぞれ一ヶ月の賃銀を計算して、山と積まれた給料袋の中へ、当日銀行から引き出された、大トランクに一杯もあろうという、二十円、十円、五円などの紙幣を汗だくになって、詰め込んでいるさなかに、事務所の玄関へ一人の紳士が訪れた。

Especially in that part (By the way how do you call a subpart of a Japanese sentence between two commas ? A clause ?) :

> 山**と**積まれた給料袋の中へ

I guess the meaning is

> The salary envelopes were piling up like a mountain.

Is と used here to mean "like, similar to" or am I wrong ? Is there any link/resource to explain more on that case of と ?

Comment: [This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76896/43676) contains a link which leads to other links.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! と is used to mean "similar to" here.

It is intended to emphasize many salary envelopes which are likened to a mountain!