# What does あったりと mean?

Tags: particles, particle-と

> 僕の住まう差大角豆(ささげ)町の町並みは都会とは程遠く、木々が街道を飾り、町の至る所に雑木林があったりと、とても長閑(のどか)な町だ。

Is the あったりと connected to the last part of the sentence through the 〜たりする grammar? If so, what does "と" mean in "あったりと"?

I know that in 〜たりする its last use can omit the する, but since in this case the sentence ends with だ, is it the same thing? I mean, is it possible to use this grammar with the last part of the sentence being です or だ (which in this case the する **has** to be omitted)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This と is a kind of "listing" particle. Please see [Function of と when used with 続く](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68125/5010) for similar examples. In this sentence, it is marking two reasons/examples regarding the statement 長閑な町だ (ie, "There are 木々 and there are 雑木林, so this is a 長閑な town.").

Sometimes a writer uses only one たり even when two items are explicitly present. (I personally dislike it, though.) Here, the "list" consists of 木々が街道を飾る and 雑木林がある. This sentence could have written like this:

> 木々が街道を飾ってい**たり**、町の至る所に雑木林があっ**たり**と、とても長閑な町だ。

Comment: Thank you for answering me! I read the linked article. It's very different to see たりと used in that way. Also, I didn't know that different use of たり you explained. Is the last part of the sentence, とても長閑な町だ, "omitting" the する of the たり? I mean, could it end with "...町だったりする"? It's just that I never saw this pattern: 〜たり、〜たり、〜だ...

Comment: @big95 No, 長閑な町だ is a *conclusion*, and it does not belong to the list of the reasons marked with たり. と indicates the end of the list.

Comment: Also, in the example sentences from the link you sent, I saw only nouns being used, but in the sentence I wrote here, there are two relative sentences (I hope these are relative sentences). I know this question may sound  useless considering the example sentence, but can this と be used with any relative sentence to describe something?

Comment: Answering the first  comment: hmm... but I don't know where する would fit. Can する be placed before と in this case? I'm sorry that I didn't understand...

Comment: AたりBたり actually behaves like a noun (eg 寝たり起きたりを繰り返す, 食べたり飲んだりは禁止します), and that's why it *often* takes する. In this case, however, no する is omitted because this type of と takes a list of nouns. The example about 典型的なオタク is the closest to your sentence.

Comment: お〜, now I understand! I tried to search more about たり as a noun, but all the results is "〜たりする", only a comment in another website. Basically, your example sentences are a sequence of actions being used as a noun, right?

Comment: @BIG-95 It's not a "sequence" (たり doesn't imply something happens *after* another), but you can think of it as a noun phrase, like "things like eating and drinking", which you can "do" (する). (BTW 木々が街道を飾る is not a noun, and that's why I dislike the partial omission of たり...)

Comment: I know this is an old question and this comment is not relevant according to the website rules, but I'm reviewing the basics and I just wanted to thank you very much. Your explanation is so detailed and revealing, because I really didn't found information about this. Your exemple sentences above about たり using other particles like を and は are absolutely useful for me who want to be fluent in Japanese. Thank you very much.