# What does 集線 mean?

Tags: words, word-requests

Full text: VPNにおける対向拠点は最大1000対地（拡張メモリ搭載時）、ISDN同時接続可能な対向拠点は46対地（PRI拡張モジュール×2搭載時）と、大規模なネットワークの集線に対応しています。

My understanding: There is a maximum of 1000 tunnels at the opposite VPN end-point (with extended memory installation), at the same time the possible ISDN end-point connections are at 46 tunnels (with 2 PRI extended module installations), supporting large-scale network hub/concentrator.

My Issue: 集線. I understand that it is a networking connection device. Does it mean a hub or concentrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

集線 is not a device name but an *action* name (i.e., suru-verb) that means 集 ("aggregating", "assembling", "collecting") + 線 ("cable", "line").

Note that と before this part is not "and" but [this "content-descriptor" と](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/68132/5010). Thus, this 集線 refers to what **this** router can achieve by connecting to many endpoints. The device that does only 集線 is called a hub (e.g. an USB hub), but a router can do 集線, too.

> …と、大規模なネットワークの集線に対応しています。
> ..., thus enabling/realizing a large-scale network concentration.

Comment: I didn't know about the "content-descriptor" と. Thank you for your help.