# Can と見る be used instead of と言う

Tags: grammar, word-usage, particle-と

Can 見る be used rather than 言う in this context？

Why is this written:

> 「なぜ止まったんだ」と僕を見ました。

<sup>*Short Stories in Japanese for Intermediate Learners* by Olly Richards, page 22</sup>

I would maybe have expected this:

> 「なぜ止まったんだ」と僕を言いました。

It’s odd to say that I **saw** him saying something, unless the implication is he **seemed** to be saying something?

Comment: Two things: first, 僕 is marked with を, i.e. is the object rather than the subject of 見ました; and just because と is used quotatively doesn't mean that the quoted thing was *said* - [check out the category](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-%e3%81%a8). Maybe https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/68125 in particular will be helpful for you.

Comment: I don't feel confident writing up a full answer for this, but: I would interpret this as "He looked at me *as if to say* 'just why, exactly, did you stop?'".

Comment: Reading the [context of the original story](https://books.google.com/books?id=wfE3EAAAQBAJ&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22#v=onepage&q&f=false), I _think_ this is quoted direct speech instead of "as if" direct speech, but maybe a native speaker can correct my instincts here. I admit I doubted myself as to which it should be.

Comment: "He looked at me as if saying x", or "He looked at me as if asking y", is how I would phrase this imo.

Comment: 僕を言いました makes no sense regardless of what you wanted it to mean.

Comment: @jogloran - That's how I understand it, too, but 「なぜ止まったんだ」と言って僕を見ました might have been better for a content intended for intermediate learners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpretation is:

> He looked at me, asking 'Why have we stopped?'

rather than

> I saw him saying 'Why have we stopped'?

と in this instance is specifying the manner in which the other person looked at the speaker — it's a bit weird to think of direct speech as indicating a way of doing something (as if it were "He looked at me in a 'Why have we stopped' way" in English), but I interpret と here as being similar to expressions such as:

> ドアがバタンと閉まった。 
> The door closed with a bang.